# Sort a matrix with another matrix

Tags: matlab, bsxfun

Suppose I have a matrix `A` and I sort the rows of this matrix. How do I replicate the same ordering on a matrix `B` (same size of course)?

E.g.

```
A = rand(3,4);
[val ind] = sort(A,2);
B = rand(3,4);
%// Reorder the elements of B according to the reordering of A
```

This is the best I've come up with

```
m = size(A,1);
B = B(bsxfun(@plus,(ind-1)*m,(1:m)'));
```

Out of curiosity, any alternatives?

**Update:** [Jonas' excellent solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679022/sort-a-matrix-with-another-matrix/2679517#2679517) profiled on 2008a (XP):

#### n = n

```
0.048524       1.4632       1.4791        1.195       1.0662        1.108       1.0082      0.96335      0.93155      0.90532      0.88976
```

#### n = 2m

```
0.63202       1.3029       1.1112       1.0501      0.94703      0.92847      0.90411       0.8849       0.8667      0.92098      0.85569
```

It just goes to show that loops aren't anathema to MATLAB programmers anymore thanks to [JITA](http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/news_notes/may03/profiler.html) (perhaps).

Comment: Lol .. it took me a second to realize you were referring to another language .. was wondering what esoteric MATLAB syntax I was looking at!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A somewhat clearer way to do this is to use a loop

```
A = rand(3,4);
B = rand(3,4);
[sortedA,ind] = sort(A,2);

for r = 1:size(A,1)
   B(r,:) = B(r,ind(r,:));
end
```

Interestingly, the loop version is faster for small (<12 rows) and large (>~700 rows) square arrays (r2010a, OS X). The more columns there are relative to rows, the better the loop performs.

Here's the code I quickly hacked up for testing:

```
siz = 10:100:1010;
tt = zeros(100,2,length(siz));

for s = siz
    for k = 1:100

        A = rand(s,1*s);
        B = rand(s,1*s);
        [sortedA,ind] = sort(A,2);

        tic;
        for r = 1:size(A,1)
            B(r,:) = B(r,ind(r,:));
        end,tt(k,1,s==siz) = toc;

        tic;
        m = size(A,1);
        B = B(bsxfun(@plus,(ind-1)*m,(1:m).'));
        tt(k,2,s==siz) = toc;

    end
end

m = squeeze(mean(tt,1));

m(1,:)./m(2,:)
```

For square arrays

```
ans =

    0.7149    2.1508    1.2203    1.4684    1.2339    1.1855    1.0212    1.0201    0.8770       0.8584    0.8405
```

For twice as many columns as there are rows (same number of rows)

```
ans =

    0.8431    1.2874    1.3550    1.1311    0.9979    0.9921    0.8263    0.7697    0.6856    0.7004    0.7314
```

Comment: +1 - Impressive! I guess the JIT is pretty powerful now. I'll post results for R2008a soon.

Answer (score 6):

Sort() returns the index along the dimension you sorted on. You can explicitly construct indexes for the other dimensions that cause the rows to remain stable, and then use linear indexing to rearrange the whole array.

```
A = rand(3,4);
B = A; %// Start with same values so we can programmatically check result

[A2 ix2] = sort(A,2);
%// ix2 is the index along dimension 2, and we want dimension 1 to remain unchanged
ix1 = repmat([1:size(A,1)]', [1 size(A,2)]); %//'
%// Convert to linear index equivalent of the reordering of the sort() call
ix = sub2ind(size(A), ix1, ix2) 
%// And apply it
B2 = B(ix)
ok = isequal(A2, B2) %// confirm reordering
```

Comment: Nice. It would be interesting to compare timing for this solution as well.

Comment: On the surface, it looks very similar to mine except I manually compute the linear indices and use `bsxfun`.

Comment: Sad to say it's a loser performancewise. On my R2010a, this is about 25% slower than either the loop or bsxfun solution.

Comment: @Jacob: I think you're right, and I just had trouble reading the bsxfun() code. This doesn't seem like an improvement on OP after all.

Comment: @Andrew Janke: I initially wrote something very similar to your solution. Only then did I figure out the bsxfun call. That's why I wrote the loop is 'clearer' :). In general, bsxfun calls should not be allowed to exist without comments.

Comment: @Jonas: I don't know really, it's very similar to using `repmat`. But yes, I agree, the loops are clearer and seem to be more efficient.

Comment: @Jacob: `repmat` has only a single function. When I thus read `repmat`, I know what's going to happen. When I read `bsxfun`, I know that I have to really pay attention now. Having said that, it makes me happy every time I get to write `bsxfun`. bsxfun bsxfun bsxfun

Comment: @Jonas: Lots of fun, isn't it :D. I used to think `bsxfun` performed the function on the rows/columns thus avoiding allocating another matrix with `repmat` but this does not seem to be true since both failed for the large matrices.

Comment: @Jacob: Very interesting, thanks for sharing the observation!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do this?

```
[val ind]=sort(A);
B=B(ind);
```

It worked for me, unless I'm understanding your problem wrong.

Comment: `ind` contains only row indices. `B = B(ind)` does not give the result required.