# Change indexes of element in one matrix based on operation in another in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

Suppose I have the following matrices:

```
    >> A = [1 3 5;6 8 11]
    >> flagA=ones(size(A))
    >> B = [4;12]
    >> flagB=[2;2]
    >> C=[A,B]
```

Thus, matrices look like follows:

```
    A =

 1     3     5
 6     8    11

    flagA =

 1     1     1
 1     1     1

    B =

 4
12

    flagB =

 2
 2

    C =

 1     3     5     4
 6     8    11    12
```

I want to sort each row in C in increasing order, so we get

```
    sortedC =
 1  3  4  5
 6  8  11 12
```

and get a flagC matrix that contains the corresponding the flagA and flagB elements in the sortedC matrix

```
    flagC =
 1  1  2  1
 1  1  1  2
```

I know how to sort each row in C to get sortedC. But how do we obtain the flagC matrix based on the sortedC matrix?

Comment: A solution can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679022/sort-a-matrix-with-another-matrix

Comment: Thanks Daniel for pointing to the right link, I am sorry for not finding that myself.