# Sort a matrix according to ordering in another matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting, matrix, indexing

I am trying to sort an array based on another array.  I tried the sort method with index return, but it is somehow behaving strangely.

```
y = [1 2 3; 2 3 4] 
x = [1 3 4; 2 2 3] 
[yy, ii] = sort(y,'descend');
```

```
yy =
   2     3     4   
   1     2     3

ii =
   2     2     2
   1     1     1
```

But my `x(ii)` is not the matrix sorted based on `y`.

```
x(ii) =  
      2     2     2
      1     1     1
```

I am expecting the matrix to be:

```
x(ii) =

    2     2     3 
    1     3     4
```

How can I sort the matrix `x` according to another matrix `y`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort a matrix with another matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679022/sort-a-matrix-with-another-matrix)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ii` are row subscripts but are being inputted by you as linear indices.
You need to convert them to relevant linear indices before proceeding i.e.

```
>> szx =  size(x);
>> x(sub2ind(szx, ii, repmat(1:szx(2),szx(1),1)))

ans =

     2     2     3
     1     3     4
```